# Java and HTML confusion on the JSP

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am trying to print the status in different colours using bootstrap but this prints nothing. Please can somebody help to figure out my mistake.

```
<% if (a.getStatus() == "OnTime")
{%>
<td class="btn-success"><%= a.getStatus()%></td>  
<% } else if (a.getStatus() == "Delayed")
{%> <td class="btn-warning"><%= a.getStatus()%></td>  
<% } else if (a.getStatus() == "Canceled")
{%> <td class="btn-danger"><%= a.getStatus()%></td>  F
<% } else
{ %> <td> </td> <% } %>
```

Comment: Maybe it's about time java compiler throw a warning when someone attempts to compare a string with `==`. Newbies always stumbles here..

Comment: Two main problems: 1) Use `equals` rather than `==` to compare `String`s. 2) [**Don't use scriptlets, it's discouraged**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Instead, use Expression Language and libraries like JSTL where you can effectively compare strings by using `==` with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe status is not initialized.

You must compare string content with

```
<% if (a.getStatus().equals("OnTime") )
```

Or

```
<% if (a.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("OnTime") )
```

And just for debugging in last line put

```
{ %> <td> <%= a.getStatus()%> </td> <% } %>
```

to see de actual status method result.